# Gradles maven-publish plugin eating the heap (1GB) when publishing a large (350MB) file

Tags: gradle, out-of-memory

I'm publishing a number of artifacts to Sonatype Nexus using the maven-publish plugin. Most of these artifacts are less than 10Mb in size and all get published fine.

One of the artifacts however is ~350Mb. When I try to publish it I get the following output ("blah" replaces names my employer might not like me posting on the web):

```
Publishing to repository org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.DefaultMavenArtifactRepository_Decorated@193cb40
[ant:null] Deploying to http://blah:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/
Uploading: blah/blah/blah/blah/blah/1.3.888/blah-1.3.888.zip to repository remote at http://blah:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/
Transferring 349480K from remote
:publishReleaseArtifactPublicationToMavenRepository FAILED
:publishReleaseArtifactPublicationToMavenRepository (Thread[Daemon,5,main]) completed. Took 8.94 secs.

...

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':publishReleaseArtifactPublicationToMavenRepository'.
> Java heap space

* Try:
Run with --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':publishReleaseArtifactPublicationToMavenRepository'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:296)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:86)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:148)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:105)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:85)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:81)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildModelAction.run(BuildModelAction.java:45)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildModelAction.run(BuildModelAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ConfiguringBuildAction.run(ConfiguringBuildAction.java:143)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartStopIfBuildAndStop.execute(StartStopIfBuildAndStop.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ReturnResult.execute(ReturnResult.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:71)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:69)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:69)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator.runCommand(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:184)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.doBuild(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:49)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.HandleStop.execute(HandleStop.java:30)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonHygieneAction.execute(DaemonHygieneAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.CatchAndForwardDaemonFailure.execute(CatchAndForwardDaemonFailure.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DefaultDaemonCommandExecuter.executeCommand(DefaultDaemonCommandExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler$ConnectionWorker.handleCommand(DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler.java:155)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler$ConnectionWorker.receiveAndHandleCommand(DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler.java:128)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler$ConnectionWorker.run(DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler.java:116)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.AbstractWagon.transfer(AbstractWagon.java:492)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.AbstractWagon.transfer(AbstractWagon.java:457)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.AbstractWagon.putTransfer(AbstractWagon.java:411)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.AbstractWagon.transfer(AbstractWagon.java:392)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.AbstractWagon.putTransfer(AbstractWagon.java:365)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.put(StreamWagon.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.manager.DefaultWagonManager.putRemoteFile(DefaultWagonManager.java:317)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.manager.DefaultWagonManager.putArtifact(DefaultWagonManager.java:227)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.ant.DeployTask.doExecute(DeployTask.java:125)
    at org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.ant.CustomDeployTask.doExecute(CustomDeployTask.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.ant.AbstractArtifactTask.execute(AbstractArtifactTask.java:751)
    at org.gradle.api.publish.maven.internal.publisher.AbstractAntTaskBackedMavenPublisher.execute(AbstractAntTaskBackedMavenPublisher.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.publish.maven.internal.publisher.AbstractAntTaskBackedMavenPublisher.publish(AbstractAntTaskBackedMavenPublisher.java:61)
    at org.gradle.api.publish.maven.internal.publisher.StaticLockingMavenPublisher.publish(StaticLockingMavenPublisher.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.publish.maven.internal.publisher.ValidatingMavenPublisher.publish(ValidatingMavenPublisher.java:48)
    at org.gradle.api.publish.maven.tasks.PublishToMavenRepository$2.publish(PublishToMavenRepository.java:148)
    at org.gradle.api.publish.internal.PublishOperation.run(PublishOperation.java:37)
    at org.gradle.api.publish.maven.tasks.PublishToMavenRepository.doPublish(PublishToMavenRepository.java:142)
    at org.gradle.api.publish.maven.tasks.PublishToMavenRepository.publish(PublishToMavenRepository.java:133)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:218)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:211)
```

I've watched this running in VisualVM and seen that the heap spikes qucikly from ~100Mb to >1Gb (as I'm running with -Xmx1G) before this exception is thrown.

A heap dump suggests that the memory is been allocated by sun.net.www.http.PosterOutputStream which is used by LightweightHttpWagon?

I've tried this in Gradle versions 1.8, 1.10, and 2.0.

Has anybody else seen this?

Any fixes/workarounds?

My script looks something like this:

```
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

task publishAsZip(type: Zip) {
    if (!rootProject.hasProperty('releaseRoot')) {
        println 'The release root directory has not been specified - skipping task'
    } else {
        from new File(targetRoot, "files")
        baseName 'app'
        destinationDir  new File(releaseRoot, "Build $jenkinsBuildNumber")
        version  "${appVersion}-win-${jenkinsBuildNumber}"

        publishing {
            publications {
                releaseArtifact(MavenPublication) {
                    groupId 'blah.blah.blah'
                    artifactId 'blah-app'
                    version "1.3.${jenkinsBuildNumber}"
                    artifact publishAsZip
                }
           }
            repositories {
                maven {
                    credentials {
                        username 'deploymentUser'
                        password 'deploymentPass'
                    }
                    url "http://nexusserver:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find a workaround?

Comment: I did! See my answer below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I went came up with this (using WebDav to deploy to Nexus):

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'

configurations {
    ...
    wagonJars
}

dependencies {
    ...
    wagonJars 'org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-webdav-jackrabbit:2.7'
}

task buildRelease(type: Zip) {
    ...
}

artifacts {
    archives buildRelease
}

uploadArchives {
    repositories.mavenDeployer {
        configuration = configurations.wagonJars
        repository(url: 'dav:http://.../') {
            authentication(userName: '...', password: '...')
        }
        pom.groupId = '...'
        pom.artifactId = '...'
        pom.version = "..."
    }
}
```

Comment: Right, so use the old maven plugin instead of the new maven-publish plugin, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue with a ~270mb file. I fixed it by upgrading my gradle(wrapper) to the latest version of gradle (2.11).

Comment: Great! Good to know they've fixed it.